# Why is the second CUDA kernel needed for computing the single source shortest path?

Tags: cuda

I have implemented single source shortest path algorithm on CUDA by referring to a research paper.
There are two kernels as follows

```
__global__ void SSSP_kernel_1(Node* d_node, int* d_edges, int *d_weights, bool* d_mask, int* d_cost, int *d_costU, unsigned long long no_of_nodes) { 
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(tid < no_of_nodes && d_mask[tid]) { 
        d_mask[tid] = false;
        for(int i = d_node[tid].start; i < (d_node[tid].start + d_node[tid].num); i++) { 
            int id = d_edges[i];
            if(d_costU[id] > (d_cost[tid] + d_weights[i]))
            d_costU[id] = d_cost[tid] + d_weights[i]; 
        } 
    } 
} 

__global__ void SSSP_kernel_2(Node* d_node, int* d_edges, int *d_weights, bool* d_mask, int* d_cost, int *d_costU, unsigned long long no_of_nodes, bool *d_stop) { 
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(tid < no_of_nodes) {
        if(d_cost[tid] > d_costU[tid]) {
            d_cost[tid] = d_costU[tid];
            d_mask[tid] = true;
            *d_stop = false;
        }
        d_costU[tid] = d_cost[tid];
    }
}
```

The cost is computed using an intermediate array and a second kernel is launched to update the cost values. The authors say " Updating the cost at the time of modification itself
can result in read after write inconsistencies." But I fail to see why. Even if there is read after write, I would be updating (line 8, kernel 1) only the least value which is what is anyway needed. What am I missing here?
Thank you for your time

EDIT:
The paper I referred to
http://cvit.iiit.ac.in/papers/Pawan07accelerating.pdf (page 7)

Comment: Would not the same thing happen even when updating d_costU (the intermediate array)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After careful reading of the paper you linked to, here are my thoughts. Sorry, it's a bit long, please bear with me.

By merging both kernels into a single one, we get the following implementation, which I hope you will agree with:

```
__global__ void SSSP_kernel(Node* d_node, int* d_edges, int *d_weights,
                            bool* d_mask, int* d_cost, int *d_costU,
                            unsigned long long no_of_nodes, bool *d_stop) {
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (tid < no_of_nodes && d_mask[tid]) {
        d_mask[tid] = false;

        for (int i = d_node[tid].start; i < (d_node[tid].start + d_node[tid].num); i++) {
            int id = d_edges[i];

            if (d_cost[id] > (d_cost[tid] + d_weights[i])) {
                d_cost[id] = (d_cost[tid] + d_weights[i]);
                d_mask[id] = true;
                *d_stop = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let's assume that this is the kind of implementations the author were referring to when mentioning read-after-write hazards. If this assumption is false, then this answer is probably meaningless. But let's assume it is true and continue: *where could read-after-write hazards occur?*

As Robert Crovella said in his (now deleted) answer, there are only two interesting locations where there are *writes* in the kernel: `d_cost` and `d_mask`. Let's examine both.

**1. Writes to** `d_cost`

Consider the following code stanza:

```
if (d_cost[id] > (d_cost[tid] + d_weights[i])) {
    d_cost[id] = (d_cost[tid] + d_weights[i]);
    ...
}
```

A hazard may happen if `d_cost[tid]` is written to *between* the `if` condition and body. The result is that the new value of `d_cost[id]` is inconsistent. Is it problematic? I believe it is not: the value of `d_cost[tid]` can only have decreased, so the condition is not violated. That precise hazard can be solved by introducing an auxiliary variable, like this:

```
int cost = d_cost[tid] + d_weights[i];
if (d_cost[id] > cost) {
    d_cost[id] = cost;
    ...
}
```

A hazard can still happen, but on the value of `d_cost[id]` now: it is possible to overwrite a "better cost" with a cost that is not better (which would violate the condition). Is it problematic? Again, I believe it is not: it will only delay finding the correct solution, not prevent it. In fact, this hazard can *also* happen in the 2-kernel version you posted, and you said it yourself in the comments. This could be solved through the use of atomic instructions (and the authors mention it in the paper).

I think these two hazards, all others things being equal, do not prevent the algorithm from converging to the correct solution, but they will put the cost matrix in an inconsistent state (temporarily).

**2. Writes to** `d_mask`

Everytime the cost of a node `id` is updated, it is flagged as *must-refresh-cost-of-neighbors* with the line:

```
d_mask[id] = true;
```

That's one write to `d_mask`. The other write is when checking whether the node neighbors must be refreshed:

```
if (tid < no_of_nodes && d_mask[tid]) {
    d_mask[tid] = false;
```

So how can these operations be sequenced?

An option is that the write to `true` may happen *after* the write to `false`: the final value of `d_mask[tid]` is `true`. It's not an issue, as it doesn't affect the correctness of the algorithm: the node will be visited again (maybe redundantly) on the next iteration, and the neighbors will be refreshed.

But consider what happens when the write to `true` happens *before* the write to `false`: the final value of `d_mask[tid]` will be `false`. That means the node will *not* be visited again on the next iteration, and therefore all costs computed in the current iteration will be frozen, possibly forever. So they must be computed correctly, using the latest available costs that were calculated on the thread that set the mask to `true`. But since SMs have no way of synchronizing their memory operations, these may not be available yet. This may prevent the algorithm from converging to the correct solution. This hazard would disappear with the use of atomics, as the authors mention.

In conclusion, the read-after-write hazards appear because *only a subset of the nodes* are refreshed from iteration to iteration: if all nodes were refreshed at every step, the algorithm would always converge to the correct solution.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for explaining in detail. If I understand correctly, you point out that there is no problem in updating the cost values - though hazards exist, will be resolved in the following iterations. The hazard exists at d_mask. The point where d_mask is set to false is when a node is refreshing its neighbors, so even if it overwrites a true value, would it not refresh using the latest cost values (updated by the thread which is setting it true) and hence there would still not be any wrong calculations?

Comment: You are right, I ran both the 2-kernel and the 1-kernel version and some of the vertices are frozen with higher costs. But I am unable to see the reason when I see the code as pointed out in my previous comment.

Comment: RE your first comment (it's almost correct!): when `d_mask` is set to `false`, a node refreshes its neighbors using the latest available values. If these values were computed on the same SM, then they certainly are available to that thread. But if they were computed on another SM, this is not guaranteed, because of how the memory subsystem works (caches, etc). The latest values *would be* available to all threads on the next kernel launch, but by then `d_mask` was set to `false`, so the refresh doesn't happen. That's what causes the hazards: the node is frozen with an incorrect cost.

Comment: Oh I always thought any update to the global memory will be consistent across various SMs. Is there any document I can read further about the same? Also, if I have to write this code using a single kernel - I need to atomically update both the mask and cost values?

Comment: You may want to read on the memory hierarchies of your specific device and its cache mechanisms (it varies between architectures). If you want to write this code using a single kernel, only the costs would need to be updated atomically (provided my analysis is correct).

Answer (score 2):

Breaking the operations in two kernels is performed by the Authors due to a synchronization need since in this way they make the cost updates visible to all the threads.

In the first kernel, all the vertices selected by `d_mask` are visited and the new cost to their corresponding neighbors evaluated. If the current cost `d_cost[tid]` plus the edge weight `d_weights[i]` is less than the old cost `d_costU[id]`, then the cost must be updated. The update must be performed in the old cost variable `d_costU[id]` otherwise, if it were operated in the current variable `d_cost[tid]`, that update would be visible to only a subset of the threads.

The second kernel checks if a smaller cost has been found for each vertex and, if so, marks it as needing visitation and updates the current cost variable `d_cost[tid]`. The old cost variable `d_costU[tid]` is then set to the current one `d_cost[tid]`.

Comment: Hi, Even if it is available only to a subset of variables in the current iteration, will it not be available for all the threads during the next iteration?